# How do I remove this character <U+2028> from my string in java?

Tags: java, string

My string is coming as sampleString followed by U+2028 in angular brackets" . Some unwanted characters are coming. From some googling, i found that this is a line separator.

I have tried trimming it using trim function. But, it is still coming.

What are the other alternatives ?

Comment: would it be easier to filter by letting through only allowed characters (say `[0-9a-zA-Z]`)?

Comment: Can you show some code to illustrate what you tried?

Comment: `s = s.replace("\u2028", "\r\n")` or replace it with "". I assume U+2028 in angular brackets is a representation of the editor with which you opened the text.

Comment: I did not open in an editor. Some of my validation failed and then i checked the logs. There I saw it like that. Let me try with s.replace("\u2028", "") as I just don't want those unwanted chars and i want my original string.

Answer (score 0):

s.replace("\u2028", "") worked for me as suggested by @joop-eggen in comments.